# Understanding Vue components and routing

Tags: vue.js

I am learning [how to build a website using a Vue frontend and Express REST backend](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fa4cRMaTDUI&list=PLWKjhJtqVAbnadueQ-C5keMQQiQau_i0D).

I have created new routes as follows:

#### /path/to/vue-client/routes/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Hello from '@components/HelloWorld';
import Register from '@components/Register';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'hello',
            component: Hello
        },
        {
            path: '/register',
            name: 'register',
            component: Register
        }        
    ]
});
```

#### /path/to/vue-client/src/components/Register.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <p>
     This is the registration page.
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Register',
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Now, having made these changes, I expect that when I browse to `http://localhost:8080/register`, I will see the Register page displayed, however, the browser just shows the home (irrespective of what I type in the browser url bar!).

The only way I can get the register page to be shown, is to modify App.vue directly:

#### /path/to/vue-client/src/App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <Register msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Register from './components/Register.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Register
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

How do I get a link to another page (implemented as a Single File Component) to work in Vue?

Comment: Try `@/components` instead of `@components` in the router's component imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `App.vue` you need to add a

```
<router-view></router-view>
```

that will render your component (in your case Hello or Register) when matching a specific route.

To generate a link inside a component and then navigate between route/component use

```
<router-link to="/">Go to Hello component</router-link>
```

cf VueJS router doc: **https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html**